In Delphi, using Excel2000, how to copy a row and insert it further down?
I get an error in the following code:
    const
      xlDown = -4121; // Equivalent to Excel's xlDown constant
    var
      RowRange: OLEVariant;
      iCrew: integer; // crew counter
    begin
      ...
      RowRange := ExcelWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Rows[7];
      RowRange.Copy;
      RowRange.Offset(iCrew, 0).Insert(xlDown);
  ...

The last statement fails ("Member not found"). I have a suspicion it is the Offset method it doesn't recognize?
I want to insert a copy of row 7 right under this row, and next time around under row 8; hence the offset.
I need to add that ChatGPT suggested this coding. I know by experience by now that ChatGPT often offers solutions that do not work, but I am running out of options.
I have tried different versions of rows, cells, and ranges. Also made a macro doing the operation manually:
    Rows("7:7").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Rows("8:8").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown

Not sure how to convert this into Delphi.

Offset is a property, so Ofsset[iCrew,0].
